# Why is the error ("iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers") raised?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why does the error occur when the value of of position is anything else than 1?

```
def sumarentradas(self, position):
        global dfEquipoLocal
        dfEquipoLocal.iat[position:2] += 1
        dfEquipoLocal.iat[position:5] += 1
        return dfEquipoLocal
```

I have checked the type of value of position and it remains as an integer, so why wont it allow me to increment the value?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attantion on the [documentation with examples](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html)

> Access a single value for a row/column pair by integer position.

Using this sintax `[position:2]` you are trying to get **a slice** instead of a single value from DataFrame. I guess `[position, 2]` meant to be here.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) of `iat` it explains that only single values are allowed

> Similar to iloc, in that both provide integer-based lookups. Use iat
> if you only need to get or set a single value in a DataFrame or
> Series.